# in bootstrap 4, is wrapping a checkbox in a label supported?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need to use the `<label>` wrapping approach to checkboxes, like below:

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" /> Default checkbox
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" disabled /> Disabled checkbox
    </label>
</div>
```

However, the documentation only presents the siblings approach:

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1"> Default checkbox </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2" disabled />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2"> Disabled checkbox </label>
</div>
```

I know Bootstrap 4 is a bit more picky about sibling relationships for certain classes (like the form validation).

**Are there any issues with using the wrapping label approach?**

It seems to work just fine for me, but I don't want to have to revisit it in 6 months if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for you then ok. 
But it is not supposed to work this way.

1. Bootstrap follows semantically clear markup. And from this point of view theirs documentation propose better "template" than you are going to use. Every developer after you will be puzzled with your decision and start search deeeeeep meaning of it.
2. Bootstrap (especially bootstrap 4 ) js components code relies on how bootstrap components should be located in theirs parents. It is a kind of abstraction leak. We should try to avoid it and our main method is as always to learn architecture of framework, walking mostly safe paths. To reference input and label BS will use selectors: find parent `.form-check` then search inside for something specific.  And there we could expect that  bootstrap selectors can fail with "culry" elements location.

Comment: yeah, that's kinda why I asked the question. I am not one to just leave it like this just because it works today. On the other hand, the wrapped approach will make things much, much simpler for me and my team. Otherwise, we need to find a way to generate a new UUID or something similar for each instance of our component (angular).

Comment: FWIW, I did go ahead and implement a pseudo-unique ID for each of my checkboxes in Angular. Following Bootstrap 4 documentation to the T now.